# Eclipse debug view current line

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Let's say I have 20 classes open and I am debugging the app.

I step the debugger thro its breakpoints. At a certain line, I get distracted and started scrolling thro the current source (which is like 2000 lines long). Then I started wading thro the other 19 source files.

After ten minutes wading, I wish to return to the current debug line. I had even forgotten what class it was. What is the best way? Here are my worst practices:

- click on the step into icon and then step out
- click on the step over hoping I don't miss out on anything important.
- Search for the highlighted line in the long stack of debug trace. Fiddle around to change display to high contrast and then change it back when I locate the line.

All the above is not good practice. If I am not wrong, when I used Visual Studio writing C#, we had a button that brought us right back to the current debug line.

Is there such a button in Eclipse? Why not? If not, has someone a plugin to do that?

Do you have an alternative convenient practice? A plugin would be great.

Comment: Don't write 2000 lines / class ... It's a very good solution !

Comment: I am reverse-engg someone's code.

Comment: i think it's a good feature regardless of how many lines of code are there. i miss it from visual studio. navigating to the stack trace is not as efficient as a key stroke / context menu item / button to achieve the task.

Comment: @JulienLafont not helpful

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Clicking on the top item in the debug trace will do exactly what you want.

Comment: Is there a shortcut??

Comment: Doesn't always work. See more detailed answer by @Scott Biggs.

Answer (score 5):

In some instances, clicking or double-clicking on the top item in the debug trace view will NOT work, like when you are already viewing the proper file.

Unfortunately there's no guaranteed one-click/keystroke that this works in all situations that I know of.  But this works with two clicks:

Click on any line of the debug trace EXCEPT the top line. Then click on the top line.

Good luck with the code (we all have to work in messy environments sometimes!).

Answer (score 2):

Just double click on the top item on debug trace view. it will take you to the line of code where the breakpoint is.

Answer (score 1):

Click **Suspend** (Pause icon) first.

Comment: me too, thanks. just click pause, and then click start.